# Upload documents in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am working in google app engine (python),

```
How can i upload documents like .jpg , .gif, .bmp , .doc , .docx , .pdf in google app engine ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in the blobstore:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/

> The Blobstore API allows your application to serve data objects, called blobs, that are much larger than the size allowed for objects in the Datastore service. Blobs are created by uploading a file through an HTTP request. Typically, your applications will do this by presenting a form with a file upload field to the user. When the form is submitted, the Blobstore creates a blob from the file's contents and returns an opaque reference to the blob, called a blob key, which you can later use to serve the blob.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Google drive to upload files and access Google Drive files with app engine. I prefer blobstore for serving files on the web. Images can be served using get_serving_url (high speed, low costs). I prefer Google drive if i need to edit my files.

Conclusion: the choice for blobstore or Google Drive depends on your type of file and your needs.